# Clarification on Ephemeral OS Disk Type for AKS Nodepool Standard_D4lds_v5

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I am currently using Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) and have a nodepool configured with the Standard_D4lds_v5 VM size. According to the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/dlsv5-dldsv5-series, the temporary storage for this VM size is SSD.

However, when I check the VM Scale Set (VMSS) in the Azure portal, it indicates that the storage type is Standard HDD LRS. This has led to some confusion on my end regarding the actual type of the Ephemeral OS Disk for my AKS nodepool.

So how to clarify whether the Ephemeral OS Disk for the Standard_D4lds_v5 VM size is SSD or Standard HDD LRS? Any additional information on how the Ephemeral OS Disk type is determined would also be greatly appreciated.

I check all references on learn.microsoft.com but it cannot give me an anwser.

Answer (score 0):

Since, as per Azure documentation, it says that Standard_D4ls_v5 has temporary storage that is SSD, which is remote only. In addition, You can attach data disks when the scale set is created. Thus when you have checked in Scale set it is showing attached data disk while VM scale set were created.